# When does ondevice ready happen, and how can I apply variables I get from it?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

In my Phonegap Android app, I have the following Javascript code:

```
function onDeviceready()
{
    window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url)
    {
        alert("WebIntent Fired Up! URL is " + url);
        if (url.substring(0, 37) === "https://xxxxxxx.com/confirmation.html")
        {
            alert("intent matched!");
            var params = url.substr(url.indexOf("?") + 1);
            params = params.split("&");
            var verificationData = params[0].split("=");
            var emailData = params[1].split("=");
            launchLinkEmail = emailData[1];
            launchLinkVerification = verificationData[1];
            alert("verification is " + launchLinkVerification);
            alert("email is " + launchLinkEmail);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceready, true);
});
```

The problem is that the variables `launchLinkVerification` and `launchLinkEmail` seem to get set *after* the page is loaded and the Javascript is finishing up, and so their value is empty when I try to call it anywhere that I want to use them. The alerts always display the information I want, but if I try to display them anywhere in my HTML pages, or set conditionals based on their value, neither work.

On the other hand, it seems that if I use `window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url)` anywhere other than `onDeviceready` it sometimes doesn't execute at all (or at least not under conditions that I can predict or understand), and again the variables don't get set.

Ultmately, what I want to do is:

1. Get the data from the URL that WebIntent captures.
2. If the data from WebIntent matches certain criteria, then switch to another page using `window.location = confirmation.html`
3. Fill two fields on the form on `confirmation.html` with the two variables I got from the URL that WebIntent picked up.

How do I get the data from the Webintent call, switch pages depending on what that data is, and then use that data on the new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the WebIntent plugin specifically, but if I understand your description correctly, I think you're running into a problem where you're running some JavaScript in the head or maybe in the body to configure the page the way you want it. But that code is dependent upon what happens in your onDeviceready(). The call to onDeviceready() is going to be made asynchronously at anytime PhoneGap feels it is ready. Usually it is called quickly, but quickly is a relative term.

What you likely need is someway for this async code to then trigger the code you want. JQuery provides the $.Deferred() object which you might find helpful. You can setup a Deferred, you add your other code in with Deferred.done(), and when it runs onDeviceready() resolves the object which then runs the callbacks.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/

I've used this to allow something like onDeviceready() to trigger a series of other behaviors in my application which I may not have wanted to structure into one big function.